# Jquery: Array entry return boolean instead of actual entry

Tags: jquery, arrays, boolean

I have stumbled upon a rather impossible task - or I really hope I haven't.
I am writing a script where I want to populate a html form based on a singlw dropbox entry, without the need of connecting to a database for each entry.

I write the neccessary information into a selectbox value:

```
<option value="<%=nn%>_<%=bb%>_<%=pp%>_<%=ep%>_"<%=ss%>""><%=ro("Navn")%></option>
```

Which returns the following HTML code:

```
<option value="Nuc_Thompson_nuc@boardwalk.org_99_1">Nuc Thompson<option>
```

When the user change the dropbox, this variable is sent to a script which splits it into an array:

```
function getval(sel) {

      // alert(sel.value)
        var str = sel.value;
        var res = str.split("_");
```

From there I am able to retrieve the array elements and place them into their respective form fields. "_" is the delimeter.

```
$('#Fname').val(res[0]);
$('#Sname').val(res[1]);
$('#Email').val(res[2]);
```

However, when I try to read entry 3 in the array, which in the example above is "99". The script returns a boolean number 1, instead of the actual integer (index number).

Problem is that I need the index number 99 for further calculations, but I cannot figure out how to get it from the array.

When I check the html source code, the index is stored in the selectbox value as 99. But reading it using the array referral returns 1.

Same thing happens when I try

```
alert(res[3]);
alert(res);
```

Which both return 1, even tho the sourcecode shows number 99

IF I read the entry into a formfield, it shows up as expected - with the correct index. But not when I try to read it as a variable.

```
$('#status').val(res[3]);
```

Any ideas ?

IT SEEMS I've solved it.
I read the entry into a variable in stead of reading it directly into the script.
Well - thank you :)

Comment: Can you show all your actual code together please?

Comment: Is this correct: `<option value="<%=nn%>_<%=bb%>_<%=pp%>_<%=ep%>_"<%=ss%>""><%=ro("Navn")%></option>`, is it supposed to be `<option value="<%=nn%>_<%=bb%>_<%=pp%>_<%=ep%>_<%=ss%>"><%=ro("Navn")%></option> ` ?

Comment: we want full function ?

Comment: Don't you just hate when that happens...
as soon as I posted this question, I somehow thought I would read the array entry into a variable in sted of using it directly - and it solved the entire thing.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle that demonstrates the issue. It appears to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dQzKg/